# Script to create dynamic tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I am trying to create a dynamic script to create multiple tables. Below is a sample

```
--exec USP_Dynamic_tablescript
Create procedure USP_Dynamic_tablescript
as 
    DECLARE @SQLStmt nvarchar(3000)
    DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(3000)
    DECLARE @i int

    set @i=1

    while(@i<=3)
    begin
        set @table_name = '#tblSales' + convert(varchar(10),@i)

        SET @SQLStmt = 'create  TABLE ' + @table_name +  '( ' + ' CityId int , ' +
                       ' SalesPersonId int , ' + ' SalesAmount numeric(10,2), ' +
                       ' MetTarget nvarchar(2) ' + ' ) '+
                       ' ON [PRIMARY] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)'

        print @table_name

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt

        set @i = @i + 1
    end

    SELECT * from #tblSales1

    INSERT INTO #tblSales1(CityId, SalesPersonId, SalesAmount, MetTarget) 
    VALUES (1, 101, 1650.00, 'Y')
```

I need to run a DML statement on these temp tables.

if I try, i am getting below error. Please help me to understand the scope, Tables are successfully created but how can i run DML operation on it.

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure USP_Dynamic_tablescript, Line 31
>   Invalid object name '#tblSales1'.

Comment: You are creating a **Temp table** inside a **Dynamic query** which is accessible only within the **Session of Dynamic Query** you cannot access it outside of Dynamic Query

Comment: possible duplicate of [error in creating a temp table using dynamic sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338963/error-in-creating-a-temp-table-using-dynamic-sql)

Comment: If you want to withdraw your question then delete it, but don't edit the text so that existing answers have no relation to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in the comments you cannot access a temp table **outside the scope of Dynamic query**  which is **created** inside a Dynamic query.

Alternate way is by creating a `Global TempTable` or `Physical table` which can be used outside of Dynamic Query

```
DECLARE @SQLStmt nvarchar(3000)
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(3000)
DECLARE @i int

set @i=1

while(@i<=3)
begin
    set @table_name = '##tblSales' + convert(varchar(10),@i)

    SET @SQLStmt = 'create  TABLE ' + @table_name +  '( ' + ' CityId int , ' +
                   ' SalesPersonId int , ' + ' SalesAmount numeric(10,2), ' +
                   ' MetTarget nvarchar(2) ' + ' ) '+
                   ' ON [PRIMARY] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)'

    print @table_name

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt

    set @i = @i + 1
end

SELECT * from ##tblSales1
```

---

Comment: Hi, That would work but if we are going to use Global temp table then the table would be accessible to other users, which i would avoid using it. Is there any other way or different logic?

Comment: @Thomas_ITsavvy Yes in this case it will fail. Why you want to create a table dynamically ? try to change this approach

Comment: @NoDisplayName. As per the requirement, no. of cities i receive, i need to create those many tables and store information and then link to other tables, its a big sp. If I go with your approach, please suggest, What if i drop the Global temp table end of SP, will it affect other users ?

Comment: @Thomas_ITsavvy 
Local temporary tables are visible only to their creators during the same connection to an instance of SQL Server as when the tables were first created or referenced. Local temporary tables are deleted after the user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server. Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are created, and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server. So you can drop global temp table whenever you want without

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Dynamic_tablescript
AS
DECLARE @SQLStmt NVARCHAR(3000)
    ,@table_name NVARCHAR(3000)
    ,@i INT

SET @i = 1

WHILE (@i <= 3)
BEGIN
    SET @table_name = '##tblSales' + convert(VARCHAR(10), @i)
    SET @SQLStmt = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''Tempdb..' + @table_name + ''') IS NOT NULL' + CHAR(10) + 
                    'DROP TABLE ' + @table_name + CHAR(10) + 
                    'CREATE  TABLE ' + @table_name + CHAR(10) + 
                    '(CityId int ,' + CHAR(10) + 
                    ' SalesPersonId int ,' + CHAR(10) + 
                    ' SalesAmount numeric(10,2),' + CHAR(10) + 
                    ' MetTarget nvarchar(2) )' + CHAR(10) + 
                    ' ON [PRIMARY] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)'

    PRINT @SQLStmt

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt

    SET @i = @i + 1
END

INSERT INTO ##tblSales1 (
    CityId
    ,SalesPersonId
    ,SalesAmount
    ,MetTarget
    )
VALUES (
    1
    ,101
    ,1650.00
    ,'Y'
    )

SELECT *
FROM ##tblSales1
```

Comment: This is going to drop the temp table when it is used in another session by another user, which should not happen

Comment: @NoDisplayName Yes, I agree with you, because it global temp, but I wrote this code before reading your code and comments below it, I assumed that problem was only in usage of the temp table inside procedure