# SQL Server connection context using temporary table cannot be used in stored procedures called with SqlDataAdapter.Fill

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, temp-tables

I want to have some information available for any stored procedure, such as current user. Following the temporary table method indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25582641/2780791), I have tried the following:

1) create temporary table when connection is opened

```
        private void setConnectionContextInfo(SqlConnection connection)
        {
            if (!AllowInsertConnectionContextInfo)
                return;

            var username = HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "";

            var commandBuilder = new StringBuilder($@"
CREATE TABLE #ConnectionContextInfo(
    AttributeName VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY, 
    AttributeValue VARCHAR(1024)
);

INSERT INTO #ConnectionContextInfo VALUES('Username', @Username);
");

            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// checks if current connection exists / is closed and creates / opens it if necessary
        /// also takes care of the special authentication required by V3 by building a windows impersonation context
        /// </summary>
        public override void EnsureConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                lock (connectionLock)
                {
                    if (Connection == null)
                    {
                        Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                        Connection.Open();
                        setConnectionContextInfo(Connection);
                    }

                    if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        Connection.Open();
                        setConnectionContextInfo(Connection);
                    }
                }
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Connection != null && Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    Connection.Close();

                throw new ApplicationException("Could not open SQL Server Connection.", ex);
            }
        }
```

2) Tested with a procedure which is used to populate a `DataTable` using `SqlDataAdapter.Fill`, by using the following function:

```
    public DataTable GetDataTable(String proc, Dictionary<String, object> parameters, CommandType commandType)
    {
        EnsureConnection();

        using (var command = Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            if (Transaction != null)
                command.Transaction = Transaction;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(proc, Connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = CommonConstants.DataAccess.DefaultCommandTimeout;
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = commandType;

            if (Transaction != null)
                adapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = Transaction;

            ConstructCommandParameters(adapter.SelectCommand, parameters);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                var err = String.Format("Error executing stored procedure '{0}' - {1}.", proc, ex.Message);
                throw new TptDataAccessException(err, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

3) called procedure tries to get the username like this:

```
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(128) = (select AttributeValue FROM #ConnectionContextInfo where AttributeName = 'Username')
```

but `#ConnectionContextInfo` is no longer available in the context.

I have put a SQL profiler against the database, to check what is happening:

- temporary table is created successfully using a certain SPID
- procedure is called using the same SPID

**Why is temporary table not available within the procedure scope?**

In T-SQL doing the following works:

- create a temporary table
- call a procedure that needs data from that particular temporary table
- temporary table is dropped only explicitly or after current scope ends

Thanks.

Comment: Alexei: I updated my answer to add a new Option 4, based on your comment on @Vladimir's answer about using a real table so that it can be accessed in UDFs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MINOR ISSUE: I am going to assume for the moment that the code posted in the Question isn't the full piece of code that is running. Not only are there variables used that we don't see getting declared (e.g. `AllowInsertConnectionContextInfo`), but there is a glaring omission in the `setConnectionContextInfo` method: the `command` object is created but never is its `CommandText` property set to `commandBuilder.ToString()`, hence it appears to be an empty SQL batch. I'm sure that this is actually being handled correctly since 1) I believe submitting an empty batch will generate an exception, and 2) the question does mention that the temp table creation appears in the SQL Profiler output. Still, I am pointing this out as it implies that there could be additional code that is relevant to the observed behavior that is not shown in the question, making it more difficult to give a precise answer.

THAT BEING SAID, as mentioned in @Vladimir's fine [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40648178/577765), due to the query running in a sub-process (i.e. `sp_executesql`), local temporary objects -- tables and stored procedures -- do not survive the completion of that sub-process and hence are not available in the parent context.

Global temporary objects and permanent/non-temporary objects will survive the completion of the sub-process, but both of those options, in their typical usage, introduce concurrency issues: you would need to test for the existence first before attempting to create the table, *and* you would need a way to distinguish one process from another. So these are not really a great option, at least not in their typical usage (more on that later).

Assuming that you cannot pass in any values into the Stored Procedure (else you could simply pass in the `username` as @Vladimir suggested in his answer), you have a few options:

1. The easiest solution, given the current code, would be to separate the creation of the local temporary table from the `INSERT` command (also mentioned in @Vladimir's answer). As previously mentioned, the issue you are encountering is due to the query running within `sp_executesql`. And the reason `sp_executesql` is being used is to handle the parameter `@Username`. So, the fix could be as simple as changing the current code to be the following:

   ```cs
   string _Command = @"
        CREATE TABLE #ConnectionContextInfo(
        AttributeName VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY, 
        AttributeValue VARCHAR(1024)
        );";

   using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
       command.CommandText = _Command;
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }

   _Command = @"
        INSERT INTO #ConnectionContextInfo VALUES ('Username', @Username);
   ");

   using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
       command.CommandText = _Command;

       // do not use AddWithValue()!
       SqlParameter _UserName = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128);
       _UserName.Value = username;
       command.Parameters.Add(_UserName);

       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```

   Please note that temporary objects -- local and global -- cannot be accessed in T-SQL User-Defined Functions or Table-Valued Functions.
2. A better solution (most likely) would be to use `CONTEXT_INFO`, which is essentially session memory. It is a `VARBINARY(128)` value but changes to it survive any sub-process since it is not an object. Not only does this remove the current complication you are facing, but it also reduces `tempdb` I/O considering that you are creating and dropping a temporary table each time this process runs, and doing an `INSERT`, and all 3 of those operations are written to disk twice: first in the Transaction Log, then in the data file. You can use this in the following manner:

   ```cs
   string _Command = @"
       DECLARE @User VARBINARY(128) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), @Username);
       SET CONTEXT_INFO @User;
        ";

   using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
       command.CommandText = _Command;

       // do not use AddWithValue()!
       SqlParameter _UserName = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128);
       _UserName.Value = username;
       command.Parameters.Add(_UserName);

       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```

   And then you get the value within the Stored Procedure / User-Defined Function / Table-Valued Function / Trigger via:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @Username NVARCHAR(128) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), CONTEXT_INFO());
   ```

   That works just fine for a single value, but if you need multiple values, or if you are already using `CONTEXT_INFO` for another purpose, then you either need to go back to one of the other methods described here, OR, if using SQL Server 2016 (or newer), you can use [SESSION_CONTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590806.aspx), which is similar to `CONTEXT_INFO` but is a HashTable / Key-Value pairs.

   Another benefit of this approach is that `CONTEXT_INFO` (at least, I haven't yet tried `SESSION_CONTEXT`) is available in T-SQL User-Defined Functions and Table-Valued Functions.
3. Finally, another option would be to create a global temporary table. As mentioned above, global objects have the benefit of surviving sub-processes, but they also have the drawback of complicating concurrency. A seldom-used to get the benefit without the drawback is to give the temporary object a unique, session-based *name*, rather than add a column to hold a unique, session-based *value*. Using a name that is unique to the session removes any concurrency issues while allowing you to use an object that will get automatically cleaned up when the connection is closed (so no need to worry about a process that creates a global temporary table and then runs into an error before completing, whereas using a permanent table would require cleanup, or at least an existence check at the beginning).

   Keeping in mind the restriction that we cannot pass any value into the Stored Procedure, we need to use a value that already exists at the data layer. The value to use would be the `session_id` / SPID. Of course, this value does not exist in the app layer, so it has to be retreived, but there was no restriction placed on going in that direction.

   ```cs
   int _SessionId;

   using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
       command.CommandText = @"SET @SessionID = @@SPID;";

       SqlParameter _paramSessionID = new SqlParameter("@SessionID", SqlDbType.Int);
       _paramSessionID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
       command.Parameters.Add(_UserName);

       command.ExecuteNonQuery();

       _SessionId = (int)_paramSessionID.Value;
   }

   string _Command = String.Format(@"
     CREATE TABLE ##ConnectionContextInfo_{0}(
       AttributeName VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY, 
       AttributeValue VARCHAR(1024)
     );

     INSERT INTO ##ConnectionContextInfo_{0} VALUES('Username', @Username);", _SessionId);

   using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
       command.CommandText = _Command;

       SqlParameter _UserName = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128);
       _UserName.Value = username;
       command.Parameters.Add(_UserName);

       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```

   And then you get the value within the Stored Procedure / Trigger via:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @Username NVARCHAR(128),
           @UsernameQuery NVARCHAR(4000);

   SET @UsernameQuery = CONCAT(N'SELECT @tmpUserName = [AttributeValue]
        FROM ##ConnectionContextInfo_', @@SPID, N' WHERE [AttributeName] = ''Username'';');

   EXEC sp_executesql
     @UsernameQuery,
     N'@tmpUserName NVARCHAR(128) OUTPUT',
     @Username OUTPUT;
   ```

   Please note that temporary objects -- local and global -- cannot be accessed in T-SQL User-Defined Functions or Table-Valued Functions.
4. Finally, it is possible to use a real / permanent (i.e. non-temporary) Table, provided that you include a column to hold a value specific to the current session. This additional column will allow for concurrent operations to work properly.

   You can create the table in `tempdb` (yes, you can use `tempdb` as a regular DB, doesn't need to be only temporary objects starting with `#` or `##`). The advantages of using `tempdb` is that the table is out of the way of everything else (it is just temporary values, after all, and doesn't need to be restored, so `tempdb` using `SIMPLE` recovery model is perfect), and it gets cleaned up when the Instance restarts (FYI: `tempdb` is created brand new as a copy of `model` each time SQL Server starts).

   Just like with Option #3 above, we can again use the `session_id` / SPID value since it is common to all operations on this Connection (as long as the Connection remains open). But, unlike Option #3, the app code doesn't need the SPID value: it can be inserted automatically into each row using a Default Constraint. This simplies the operation a little.

   The concept here is to first check to see if the permanent table in `tempdb` exists. If it does, then make sure that there is no entry already in the table for the current SPID. If it doesn't, then create the table. Since it is a permanent table, it will continue to exist, even after the current process closes its Connection. Finally, insert the `@Username` parameter, and the SPID value will populate automatically.

   ```cs
   // assume _Connection is already open
   using (SqlCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand())
   {
       _Command.CommandText = @"
          IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.Usernames') IS NOT NULL)
          BEGIN
             IF (EXISTS(SELECT *
                        FROM   [tempdb].[dbo].[Usernames]
                        WHERE  [SessionID] = @@SPID
                       ))
             BEGIN
                DELETE FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[Usernames]
                WHERE  [SessionID] = @@SPID;
             END;
          END;
          ELSE
          BEGIN
             CREATE TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[Usernames]
             (
                [SessionID]  INT NOT NULL
                             CONSTRAINT [PK_Usernames] PRIMARY KEY
                             CONSTRAINT [DF_Usernames_SessionID] DEFAULT (@@SPID),
                [Username]   NVARCHAR(128) NULL,
                [InsertTime] DATETIME NOT NULL
                             CONSTRAINT [DF_Usernames_InsertTime] DEFAULT (GETDATE())
             );
          END;

          INSERT INTO [tempdb].[dbo].[Usernames] ([Username]) VALUES (@UserName);
               ";

       SqlParameter _UserName = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128);
       _UserName.Value = username;
       command.Parameters.Add(_UserName);

       _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```

   And then you get the value within the Stored Procedure / User-Defined Function / Table-Valued Function / Trigger via:

   ```sql
   SELECT [Username]
   FROM   [tempdb].[dbo].[Usernames]
   WHERE  [SessionID] = @@SPID;
   ```

   Another benefit of this approach is that permanent tables are accessible in T-SQL User-Defined Functions and Table-Valued Functions.

Comment: I didn't know about `CONTEXT_INFO` and `SESSION_CONTEXT`. Nice.

Comment: i will be printing this in color and framing it on my wall

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Thanks!! :-D   FYI: I have finally had a chance to test the O.P.'s code and my option #1 and have reproduced the original error and confirmed that Option #1 does fix it. I will update tomorrow with a 4th option, based on O.P.'s comment (on Vladimir's answer) about using a real table so that it can be referenced in a UDF.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I have updated with Option #4 (after verifying that it works as described), and a little more description on some of the other items.

Answer (score 9):

As was shown in this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124053/57105), `ExecuteNonQuery` uses `sp_executesql` when `CommandType` is `CommandType.Text` and command has parameters.

The C# code in this question doesn't set the `CommandType` explicitly and it is [`Text` by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx), so most likely end result of the code is that `CREATE TABLE #ConnectionContextInfo` is wrapped into `sp_executesql`. You can verify it in the SQL Profiler.

It is well-known that `sp_executesql` is running in its own scope (essentially it is a nested stored procedure). Search for "sp_executesql temp table". Here is one example:  [Execute sp_executeSql for select...into #table but Can't Select out Temp Table Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040105/execute-sp-executesql-for-select-into-table-but-cant-select-out-temp-table-da)

So, a temp table `#ConnectionContextInfo` is created in the nested scope of `sp_executesql` and is automatically deleted as soon as `sp_executesql` returns.
The following query that is run by `adapter.Fill` doesn't see this temp table.

---

What to do?

Make sure that `CREATE TABLE #ConnectionContextInfo` statement is not wrapped into `sp_executesql`.

In your case you can try to split a single batch that contains both `CREATE TABLE #ConnectionContextInfo` and `INSERT INTO #ConnectionContextInfo` into two batches. The first batch/query would contain only `CREATE TABLE` statement without any parameters. The second batch/query would contain `INSERT INTO` statement with parameter(s).

I'm not sure it would help, but worth a try.

If that doesn't work you can build one T-SQL batch that creates a temp table, inserts data into it and calls your stored procedure. All in one SqlCommand, all in one batch. This whole SQL will be wrapped in `sp_executesql`, but it would not matter, because the scope in which temp table is created will be the same scope in which stored procedure is called. Technically it will work, but I wouldn't recommend following this path.

---

Here is not an answer to the question, but suggestion to solve the problem.

To be honest, the whole approach looks strange. If you want to pass some data into the stored procedure why not use parameters of this stored procedure. This is what they are for - to pass data into the procedure. There is no real need to use temp table for that. You can use a table-valued parameter ([T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)) if the data that you are passing is complex. It is definitely an overkill if it is simply a `Username`.

Your stored procedure needs to be aware of the temp table, it needs to know its name and structure, so I don't understand what's the problem with having an explicit table-valued parameter instead. Even the code of your procedure would not change much. You'd use `@ConnectionContextInfo` instead of `#ConnectionContextInfo`.

Using temp tables for what you described makes sense to me only if you are using SQL Server 2005 or earlier, which doesn't have table-valued parameters. They were added in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Would using global ##temporary table be a good idea? Unless you don't really care if the table is going to be accessed from every connection in the server?

Comment: @MichaelWayne, global ##temp table would work in a sense that it will be visible to the stored procedure called by `adapter.Fill`. However, it doesn't look like a good idea, precisely because it is visible by everyone. It will be hard to put a relevant `ConnectionContextInfo` into it. I added to the answer how I'd approach it (I'd use a table-valued parameter).

Comment: @VladimirBaranov this answer is excellent; however, i am finding that in my situation, sp_executesql is NOT getting executed for create temp table, i am running this: http://i.imgur.com/dUU5tMy.png and when i do a profiler trace, it's showing me sqlbatchstarted, sqlbatchcompleted, and it shows the create temp table script along with "go"

Comment: If you go global temporary or permanent (preferably permanent so that DBA management has more options), throw in a discriminator such as "this process guid" which is used to differentiate one session's attributes from another. As for the temporary table problem - it is possible for a disconnect and reconnect to get the same SPID (particularly on low traffic systems). however, As the prior commenter pointed out, if the execution is separated by a GO, for batches, then you lose access to the prior batch's temporary tables. hope this helps.

Comment: how do we force the execution to happen without a GO?

Comment: @JaazCole i do not believe that you are correct on the GO front. i've done a test where i did an ExecuteNonQuery (which happened to have appended a GO), and this command created a temp table, and then i executed another command that ran a sproc "exec mysproc @parameters...." i had mysproc raiseerror if the temp table does not exist, and it did not raise an error, furthermore, the clientprocessid and spid remain the same for the temp table creation and the subsequent sproc calls, ive tried this at least 20 times

Comment: to add to my point above, i've tried to do a little test: select * into #sdfksdfkl5
from (select 1 alex) a
go

select * from #sdfksdfkl5         and this showed that the temp table still exists

Comment: thank you very much for your insight, please let me know if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Ah, it's the table variables I was thinking of. My bad. Though the temp table isolation by connection scope is correct, even if you reconnect and get assigned the same SPID. (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx) : "Local temporary tables are visible only to their creators during the same connection to an instance of SQL." Still, that said if there's no connection interruption, the table should be available.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - Thanks for the answer. It makes perfectly sense. My quick solution was to use a persistent table which also has another advantage - I can access current username using a scalar function (temp tables are not allowed in functions). Using global temporary tables (##) is no-no for me (they look like temporary ones, but are visible to all SPIDs, so error-prone). Also, sending information as table-valued params does not work for me, since my goal was to transparently inject current user information into the context.

Comment: Regarding "GO", I think it is only interpreted by SQL utilities such as SQL Management Studio and will generate an error in other contexts (such as the query of an SqlCommand).

Comment: Vladimir: great answer (+1). I expanded on a few of the items mentioned here in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40663403/577765).

Comment: @Alexei: Yes, `GO` is only known/interpreted by client apps like SSMS, SQLCMD, etc. SQL Server knows nothing of `GO` statements and hence will get an error if you include one in the `CommandText` or in Dynamic SQL. Within app code, you can simulate a `GO` simply by replacing the `CommandText` and executing again (doesn't matter if it's `ExecuteReader`, `ExecuteScalar`, or `ExecuteNonQuery`), just as long as you don't close the `SqlConnection` between executions.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', sorry I lost track of your comments. You said above that your C# code creates #temp table without `sp_executesql` and when you call a `mysproc` stored procedure later in the same connection the SP sees the #temp table. Most likely your `CREATE TABLE` command is not wrapped into `sp_executesql` because the command doesn't have parameters. Everything seems to work as expected. So, what is your problem or concern now?

Answer (score 0):

"There are two types of temporary tables: local and global. They differ from each other in their names, their visibility, and their availability. Local temporary tables have a single number sign (#) as the first character of their names; they are visible only to the current connection for the user, and they are deleted when the user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server. Global temporary tables have two number signs (##) as the first characters of their names; they are visible to any user after they are created, and they are deleted when all users referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server." -- from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399(v=sql.105).aspx)

so the answer to your problem is put ## instead of # to make the local temporary table to global.