# SQL query runs into a timeout on a sparse dataset

Tags: sql-server, datatable

For sync purposes, I am trying to get a subset of the existing objects in a table.

The table has two fields, `[Group]` and `Member`, which are both stringified Guids.

All rows together may be to large to fit into a datatable; I already encountered an `OutOfMemory` exception. But I have to check that everything I need right now is in the datatable. So I take the Guids I want to check (they come in chunks of 1000), and query only for the related objects.

So, instead of filling my datatable once with all

```
SELECT * FROM Group_Membership
```

I am running the following SQL query against my SQL database to get related objects for one thousand Guids at a time:

```
SELECT *
FROM Group_Membership
WHERE
    [Group] IN (@Guid0, @Guid1, @Guid2, @Guid3, @Guid4, @Guid5, ..., @Guid999)
```

The table in question now contains a total of 142 entries, and the query already times out (`CommandTimeout` = 30 seconds). On other tables, which are not as sparsely populated, similar queries don't time out.

Could someone shed some light on the logic of SQL Server and whether/how I could hint it into the right direction?

I already tried to add a nonclustered index on the column `Group`, but it didn't help.

Comment: maybe you can add an identity field to the table and use that to fetch records by the thousadns ? ..where MyField < 1000

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that `WHERE IN` will be able to maximally use an index on `[Group]`, or if at all.  However, if you had a second table containing the GUID values, and furthermore if that column had an index, then a join might perform very fast.

Create a temporary table for the GUIDs and populate it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Guids (
    Guid varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Guids (Guid)
VALUES
    (@Guid0, @Guid1, @Guid2, @Guid3, @Guid4, ...)

CREATE INDEX Idx_Guid ON #Guids (Guid);
```

Now try rephrasing your current query using a join instead of a `WHERE IN (...)`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Group_Membership t1
INNER JOIN #Guids t2
    ON t1.[Group] = t2.Guid;
```

As a disclaimer, if this doesn't improve the performance, it could be because your table has low cardinality.  In such a case, an index might not be very effective.

Comment: I am right now trying to find [how to use a temporary table to load a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501877/sql-server-connection-context-using-temporary-table-cannot-be-used-in-stored-pro), but this seems a bit complicated...

Comment: @Alexander It's only complicated because maybe you haven't worked much with temp tables before...their syntax isn't too different from regular tables, except they get erased when your session ends.

Comment: I have just tried to run the same query in SSMS to check whether the temp table bring any improvement; but the original query also took only a few milliseconds in SSMS. How can a `SqlCommand` time out when the same query, run via SSMS, returns in a few milliseconds?

Comment: I don't know...perhaps there is a lot of data going out of SQL Server and this is the cause of the delay