# How to create a temp table with the structure of an existing table given only the name(sql)

Tags: sql-server

I want to try to get the structure of a table into a temp table, given the name of the table in a local var @TableName, along with two new columns. I have seen links [(such as this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040105/execute-sp-executesql-for-select-into-table-but-cant-select-out-temp-table-d) that have a similar situation, but they do not try to maintain the same structure. I have tried many variations of code (I know the current iteration is not good) and have found myself stuck.

```
declare @TableName as nvarchar(40) = 'TableVar'
declare @Query as nvarchar(250) = 'select * into #ModifiedTable
FROM (
SELECT *,''I'' creation_status, GETDATE() creation_timestamp
FROM '+@TableName+') SubQuery';
exec sp_executesql @Query
DROP TABLE #ModifiedTable
```

Comment: You don't need to use a subquery here. Not clear what the real intention is here though. Sounds a LOT like an xy problem to me. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

When you need to make a temp with the exact same schema, the easiest way is to do something like :

```
declare @TableName as nvarchar(40) = 'TableVar'
declare @Query as nvarchar(4000) 
SET @Query = 'select * 
into #ModifiedTable
FROM '+@TableName+' 
where 1=2';
print @query
exec sp_executesql @Query
```

The trick here is the 1=2. This guarantees no rows are returned, but the full schema is put into the temp table. Note I through a print statement in just so you can see the query to copy/paste debug.

Comment: Note that #ModifiedTable will be automatically dropped before sp_executesql returns, so you can't use it from the enclosing batch.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for mentioning that, I noticed it in testing, but assumed OP knew, but that might be the main problem :)